# Tidying data in R

Tags: r

I'm super new to R overall and I'm working with a long dataframe with the ultimate goal of creating a density plot.  The dataframe is just two variables of heights; one fheight and the other sheight for father and son respectively.  I need to rearrange this data so that the varibles are in another column "relationships" with father and son and the corresponding heights (160, 175, etc...).

library(dplyr)

| father_height | son_height |
| --- | --- |
| 165.2 | 151.8 |
| 160.7 | 160.6 |
| 165.0 | 160.9 |

The ultimate goal here is to create a density plot with both of these measured. Any help would be amazing.

ETA:  My expected output would be similar to below:

| relationships | heights |
| --- | --- |
| father | 165.2 |
| son | 151.8 |
| father | 160.7 |

Comment: What is your expected output based on the example you shared? ALso please make reproducible examples (use `dput()`)

Comment: I added the output expectation.  I'm unfamiliar with dput().  =/

Comment: Ok so you just want to convert to long. Take a look at the answer I closed it with

Comment: Thanks!  Gather worked.  I don't know why that was so freaking confusing.  appreciate the guidance.